# Need help building the correct name string for multidimensional form post

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this form

```
name="field_group1[0][ field_name_fg1 ]"

name="field_group1[0][ field_group2[0][ field_name_fg2 ] ]"

name="field_group1[0][ field_group2[0][ field_group3[0][ field_name_fg3 ] ] ]"

name="field_group1[0][ field_group2[0][ field_group3[0][ field_name2_fg3 ] ] ]"

name="field_group1[0][ field_group2[0][ field_group3[1][ field_name_fg3 ] ] ]"

name="field_group1[0][ field_group2[0][ field_group3[1][ field_name2_fg3 ] ] ]"
```

$_POST debug var

```
'field_group1' => array (
    0 => array (
       'field_name_fg1' => 'string',
       'field_group2[0' => array (
           'field_name_fg2' => 'string',
           'field_group3[0' => array (
               'field_name_fg3' => 'string',
               'field_name2_fg3' => 'string',
           )
           'field_group3[1' => array(
               'field_name_fg3' => 'string',
               'field_name2_fg3' => 'string',
           )
       )
    )
)
```

The value structure that I think the correct one should be like this, at least this is the results that I'm looking for:

```
    'field_group1' => array (
        0 => array( 
            'field_name_fg1' => 'string',
            'field_group2' => array(
               0 => array(
                   'field_name_fg2' => 'string',
                   'field_group3' => array(
                       0 => array (
                           'field_name_fg3' => 'string',
                           'field_name2_fg3' => 'string',
                       ),
                       1 => array (
                           'field_name_fg3' => 'string',
                           'field_name2_fg3' => 'string',
                       )
                   )
               )
           )
       )
   )
```

which part of the naming structure for `name` attributes that is incorrect in my case?

I've tried with this structure `field_group[0]field_group2[0]field_group3[0]` and still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of `keys` in array should be braced. Set your form input `name` attributes according to the following format:

```
<input type='text' name="field_groups[field_group1][0][field_group2][0][field_group3][0][field_name_fg3]">
```

The resulting output will be as shown below:

```
array (size=1)
  'field_group1' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'field_group2' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => 
                array (size=1)
                  'field_group3' => 
                    array (size=1)
                      0 => 
                        array (size=1)
                          'field_name_fg3' => string 'fg3name'
```